# less mixins do not work

Tags: less, mixins

I have recently decided to use LESS.
So I am doing the migration from css to less.

There is definitively something I do not understand about mixins.
I read the doc, of course, and read some stuffs about mixins. I have done some research on StackOverflow, and I did not find any anwser.

I have this less code:

```
navbar{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2px;

  .mixin-subtitle{
    display: block;
    background: @white;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 1px;
    padding-left: 10%;
    line-height: 24px;
  }
  .mixin-type{
    font-family: 'icon-mvp';
    height: 100%;
    width: 9.5%;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(156,178,189,0.65);
    left: 1px;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px @blue;
  }
  .artist{

    subtitle{
      .mixin-subtitle();
    }
    .type{
      .mixin-type();

      &:before{
        content: "\e607";
      }
    }
  }
  .album{

    subtitle{
      .mixin-subtitle();
    }
    .type{
      .mixin-type();

      &:before{
        content: "\e608";
      }
    }
  }
  .song{

    subtitle{
      .mixin-subtitle();
    }
    .type{
      .mixin-type();

      &:before{
        content: "\e614";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the mixins do not work. I have tried to put the mixins in the beginning of my file. I have tried to put () after my mixins declarations.
And it still does not work...
For now I am compiling less on live with less.js, I have tried to compile it by myself with lessc, it still does not work.
I can not understand why.

Can someone help me ?

***Edit:***

there is something I do not understand.
If I put subtitle or .type as brother's of my mixins, it works.
But if I put it under artist, or song, or album, it does not...

So in this code, mixins are called :

```
navbar {
...

.mixin-type{
    font-family: 'icon-mvp';
    height: 100%;
    width: 9.5%;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(156,178,189,0.65);
    left: 1px;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px @blue;
  }

.type{
      .mixin-type();

      &:before{
        content: "\e607";
      }
   }
}
```

There is definitively something I do not understand with mixins ...

***EDIT2***

expected css :

```
.artist subtitle, .album subtitle, .song subtitle{
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 1px;
  padding-left: 10%;
  line-height: 24px;
}
.artist .type, .album .type, .song .type{
  font-family: 'icon-mvp';
  height: 100%;
  width: 9.5%;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(156,178,189,0.65);
  left: 1px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0000ff;
}
.artist .type:before{
  content: "\e607";
}
.album .type:before{
  content: "\e608";
}
.song .type:before{
  content: "\e614";
}
```

Comment: Well, your example compiles fine for (provided that I define missing `@white` and `@blue`) variables. Either way, typically it's highly useful to provide more info on what exactly is not working (i.e. what result you expect and what you get instead). Simple "it does not work" is totally useless.

Comment: All the properties defined in the mixins are not put into subtitle or type.
It compiles fine for me too.
What I want to do is as if subtitle and .type have class .mixin-type or .mixin-subtitle.

Comment: I see now. It's just the way how this works - The name of the mixin name is not appended to the rule selector the mixin is expanded in. E.g. mixins add only their properties...

Comment: Ok, instead of answering here (your example is just too long for me, sorry) I decided to slightly update the documentation itself. See the [the first example there‌](https://github.com/less/less-docs/blob/master/content/features/mixins.md)​. Notice that `.a` and `#b` selectors are not appended to `.mixin-class` and `.mixin-id` there.

Comment: > If I put .subtitle or .type as brother's of my mixins, it works.

Because there they are not mixins... There they are just simple nested rulesets.

Comment: > I put it under artist, or song, or album, it does not...
There they are mixins... You just need to understand the difference between a mixin definition (simple CSS ruleset is a mixin definition too) and a mixin call/expansion/invoking.

Comment: I'm not seeing what you are trying to achieve. You state it all compiles fine (and I agree it does), but what output are you expecting. I see all the properties placed where I believe they should be. So editing your question to show what output you are getting now and what output you are trying to get instead might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

## The Fix (I think)

Based on your edit of what you are expecting, it appears that you don't want to be doing mixins, but rather extends. In your output css you do not have noted the fact that your original code nests everything inside a `navbar` "element". Assuming that nesting is still the case, then what you really want is probably something like this:

**LESS**

```
navbar{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2px;

  .mixin-subtitle {

    display: block;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 1px;
    padding-left: 10%;
    line-height: 24px;

  }
  .mixin-type {

    font-family: 'icon-mvp';
    height: 100%;
    width: 9.5%;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(156,178,189,0.65);
    left: 1px;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #00f;

  }
  .artist{

    subtitle {
      &:extend(navbar .mixin-subtitle);
    }
    .type{
      &:extend(navbar .mixin-type);

      &:before{
        content: "\e607";
      }
    }
  }
  .album{

    subtitle {
      &:extend(navbar .mixin-subtitle);
    }
    .type{
      &:extend(navbar .mixin-type);

      &:before{
        content: "\e608";
      }
    }
  }
  .song{

    subtitle {
      &:extend(navbar .mixin-subtitle);
    }
    .type{
      &:extend(navbar .mixin-type);

      &:before{
        content: "\e614";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**CSS OUTPUT**

```
navbar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
navbar .mixin-subtitle,
navbar .artist subtitle,
navbar .album subtitle,
navbar .song subtitle {
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 1px;
  padding-left: 10%;
  line-height: 24px;
}
navbar .mixin-type,
navbar .artist .type,
navbar .album .type,
navbar .song .type {
  font-family: 'icon-mvp';
  height: 100%;
  width: 9.5%;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(156, 178, 189, 0.65);
  left: 1px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #00f;
}
navbar .artist .type:before {
  content: "\e607";
}
navbar .album .type:before {
  content: "\e608";
}
navbar .song .type:before {
  content: "\e614";
}
```

**If you in fact *do not* want `navbar` in the selector string, then you need to remove all that code from being nested inside `navbar`.**

---

### Understanding Mixins

Mixins just "copy" code to the location you specify (no grouping occurs). Your original code was doing just that when I ran it, all the properties were copying into the `navbar .artist subtitle`, `navbar .album subtitle`, etc. under their own selector blocks. The above code uses the `:extend()` to not copy code, but group the code together.

---

### Improving the Above Code

You can actually ***eliminate*** the extra `.mixin-subtitle` and `.mixin-type` classes and do your extends this way (defining it all under one of the groups, here I did `.artist`):

**LESS**

```
navbar{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2px;


  .artist {
    subtitle {
      display: block;
      background: #fff;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      left: 1px;
      padding-left: 10%;
      line-height: 24px;
    }
    .type {
      font-family: 'icon-mvp';
      height: 100%;
      width: 9.5%;
      position: absolute;
      background: rgba(156,178,189,0.65);
      left: 1px;
      font-size: 24px;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #00f;      

      &:before{
        content: "\e607";
      }
    }
  }
  .album{

    subtitle {
      &:extend(navbar .artist subtitle);
    }
    .type{
      &:extend(navbar .artist .type);

      &:before{
        content: "\e608";
      }
    }
  }
  .song{

    subtitle {
      &:extend(navbar .artist subtitle);
    }
    .type{
      &:extend(navbar .artist .type);

      &:before{
        content: "\e614";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Output CSS (Cleaner)**

```
navbar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
navbar .artist subtitle,
navbar .album subtitle,
navbar .song subtitle {
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 1px;
  padding-left: 10%;
  line-height: 24px;
}
navbar .artist .type,
navbar .album .type,
navbar .song .type {
  font-family: 'icon-mvp';
  height: 100%;
  width: 9.5%;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(156, 178, 189, 0.65);
  left: 1px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #00f;
}
navbar .artist .type:before {
  content: "\e607";
}
navbar .album .type:before {
  content: "\e608";
}
navbar .song .type:before {
  content: "\e614";
}
```

You can see that the above code does not output then output the (I am assuming) unused `.mixin-subtitle` and `.mixin-type` classes, but just simply the classes you are using.